# Gatling - decode JWT token and verify value in token

Tags: java, scala, jwt, gatling, scala-gatling

I am with Gatling tests in Scala and want to verify some fields in the decoded JWT token. I know how to decode it, but it is not possible/very slow to map the resulting JSON to an entity with Jackson like I did in Java, to check the value and/or existence.

I do some HTTP request and get a JWT token in JSON, like:

```
{"id_token":"xxxxxxx...."}
```

The token is JWT; I can decode it to get another JSON:

```
JWSObject jwsObject = JWSObject.parse(authorizeToken); // from com.nimbusds.jose.JWTObject
log.info("Decoded JWS object: {}", jwsObject.getPayload().toString());
```

It gets me:

```
{
    "sub": "c3f0d627-4820-4397-af20-1de71b208b15",
    "birthdate": "1942-11-08",
    "last_purchase_time": 1542286200,
    "gender": "M",
    "auth_level": "trusted",
    "iss": "http:\/\/somehost.com",
    "preferred_username": "test6@app.com",
    "given_name": "test6",
    "middle_name": "test6",
    "nonce": "random_string",
    "prv_member_id": 146794237,
    "aud": "some_issuer",
    "nbf": 1546869709,
    "is_premium": true,
    "updated_at": 1540812517,
    "registered_time": 1527677605,
    "name": "test6 test6 test6",
    "nickname": "test6",
    "exp": 1546870708,
    "iat": 1546869709,
    "family_name": "test6",
    "jti": "838bdd3f-1add-46f5-b3a1-cb220d3547a6"
}
```

In Java I define a DTO and convert this JSON to an instance of DTO and checks the value of each field with `Assert.assertEquals()` or something.

But, in Gatling, it is not possible:

- The conversion with Jackson is very slow, it takes me forever.
- The `check()` call is chained and cannot work like `org.junit.Assert`.

I am with:

```
  http(...).exec(...)
    .check(
      header(HttpHeaderNames.ContentType).is("application/json;charset=UTF-8"),
      jsonPath("$..id_token") exists,
      jsonPath("$..id_token").saveAs("id_token"),
      status.is(200),
    )
  )
  .exitHereIfFailed
  .exec(session => {
    val token = session("id_token").as[String]
    log.debug("Token: " + token)
    val decodedToken:String = JWSObject.parse(token).getPayload.toString()
    val dto:JWTPayloadDTO = JsonUtil.fromJson(decodedToken)  // this is very slow

    // here verification

    log.info("JWT payload: " + dto)
    session
  }
```

So, what can I do? `check()` will not work in `session => {}` part.

`JsonUtil.fromJson()`:

```
package xxx.helpers

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object JsonUtil {
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

  def fromJson[T](json: String)(implicit m : Manifest[T]): T = {
    mapper.readValue[T](json)
  }


}
```

The DTO:

```
package xxx.dto

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonNaming

@JsonNaming(classOf[PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy])
case class JWTPayloadDTO(
  aud:                String,
  iss:                String,
  exp:                Long,
  nbf:                Long,
  iat:                Long,
  sub:                String,
  authLevel:          String,
  jti:                String,
  nonce:              String,

  preferredUsername:  String,
  name:               String,
  givenName:          String,
  familyName:         String,
  middleName:         String,
  nickname:           String,
  profile:            String,
  picture:            String,
  website:            String,
  email:              String,
  emailVerified:      Boolean,
  gender:             String,
  birthdate:          String,
  zoneInfo:           String,
  locale:             String,
  phoneNumber:        String,
  phoneNumberVerified:Boolean,
  mobileNumber:       String,
  updatedAt:          Long,
  registeredTime:     Long,
  prvMemberId:        Long,
  fbUid:              String,
  lastPurchaseTime:   Long,
  isPremium:          Boolean,
  isStaff:            Boolean
)
```

Comment: The story you tell sounds very improbable. What exactly is the code behind `JsonUtil.fromJson`? How do you measure it is slow? How slow is "slow" in some absolute units of time? I will be very surprised if decoding JSON takes more time than actually making the request to the server.

Comment: `JsonUtil.fromJson()` is deserialization with Jackson. Let me add the code.

Comment: Jackson is reasonably fast. How did you measure that decoding JSON is slow comparing to making the actual request to your server? Show us some numbers and how you got those numbers.

Comment: When I uncomment this line of deserialization, `sbt gatling:test` cannot complete in 5 mins, and if commented, it completes in 1 min. I have updated the code.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't believe you pointed to the right place. If it is that slow, it should be easy to measure explicitly. Do some real profiling and show us some proofs that that line is the real showstopper rather than other things you do in your test. Alternatively create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Guess what... I change the dependency from that of Sonartype to Maven and then it starts to work. You get the point that it should be fast, but only when the dependency part works. Will add details below.

Comment: That still sounds very strange. It might have been some fluke, but if so, it might easily come back again. If I were you, I'd probably tried to investigate this more.

Answer (score 0):

At first I resort to Sonartype for dependency resolving, as the repo readme suggests:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala

`sonatype.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
```

And then add dependency in `build.sbt`.

Then I enter the module's wiki page and changed it to Maven(deleted `sonatype.sbt`)

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/wiki

only in `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.12" % "2.9.8" // latest
```

Now it begins to work.